# Weird Chrome problem

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've got a problem and I'm desperate for help.

I needed for some reason to render table header and table body separately. Each column and header cell have got same css class (eg. .col1_name). Those css classes have got declared width and text-align, and in that manner i'm making sure that header and table body cells stay aligned properly.

And, everything is OK in IE8 and Firefox. I've got problems with WebKit browsers (Chrome and Safari. Chrome is important for me.) They are rendering width of table body cells 5px less than IE and FF. I could not trace the problem, but I saw that those -5px widths are in Computed styles.

Below are s-shots and some sample code. 
[IE 8 Is just fine http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/2360/probie8.png](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/2360/probie8.png)

[Firefox is just fine http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/661/probff.png](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/661/probff.png)

[Google Chrome is not so fine http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/5176/probgc.png](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/5176/probgc.png)

[Inspecting element ...  http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/19/probj.png](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/19/probj.png)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .rbr{ width: 45px; text-align: left;}
    .sifra {width: 90px; text-align: left;}
    .naziv { width: 240px; text-align: left;} 
    .kolicina {width: 90px; text-align: right;}
    .cena {width: 60px; text-align: right;} 
</style> 

<table id="tableheader">
 <thead>
  <tr>
      <th class="rbr">RB.</th>
      <th class="sifra">Sifra</th>
      <th class="naziv">Naziv</th>
      <th class="kolicina">Kolicina</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
<table id="tablebody">
  <tbody>
   <tr> 
    <td class="rbr">1</td>
    <td class="sifra">11111112</td>
    <td class="naziv">Adelante 3 series</td>
    <td class="kolicina">2.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
    <td class="rbr">2</td>
    <td class="sifra">86868631</td>
    <td class="naziv">Canyon CNR</td>
    <td class="kolicina">1.00</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Many thanks people for any help!

Comment: That sample code doesn't seem to exhibit the problem for me in Safari or Chrome on Mac OS X. Does the sample code actually demonstrate the problem on your system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I suspect you simply have another declaration overriding the one you expect, try adding a min-width and max-width.

Answer (score 1):

@NSD you got me on right track. I re-re-re-re-viewed my entire code that is working with datagrids, and I found that body table got width set to auto.

So, thank you guys for your time.

Conclusion: if you have same cells width, but different table width (ie. xyz px / auto ) , in Chrome you'll get different cell widths.

Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I ran into this with Chrome as well.  Tables are set to table-layout:fixed and columns have well defined widths.  IE/FF both render identically in the correct sizes.  Chrome ignores my stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to also set `margin` and `padding`?

```
margin: 0;
padding: 4px;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the id is '*table-body*' but in the Chrome screenshot it says '*table-bodypozicije*'. 
Check your css for a definition of '*table-bodypozicije*' - this may be overiding your class styles applied to your td's.